# Absolute positioning of divs while Flipping a Bootstrap Thumbnail

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make "css3 on hover flip" effect work on bootstrap thumbnails. It works clean on simple divs ([JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dpkshrma/b8uL0pd1/))

Main CSS3 Code:

```
.front{
    position:absolute;
    transform:perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}
.back{
    position:absolute;
    transform:perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}
.flip3d:hover > .front{
    transform:perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
}
.flip3d:hover > .back{
    transform:perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

But when trying to use same technique with bootstrap thumbnail, the columns of respective rows containing thumbs overlap ([JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dpkshrma/vvdcaqx0/)).

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="item col-sm-6 col-md-4 flip3d">
        <div class="thumbnail front" id="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"/>
            <div class="caption">
                <span>Front1 &nbsp;</span>
                <p>Front1 Description</p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.thumbnail-->
        <div class="back thumbnail">
            Some Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am assuming this has something to do with the fact that i have used absolute positioning of .front and .back divs which is necessary for .front div to lie on top of .back

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to preserve the spacing/styling bootstrap does while using absolute positioning, you can create a wrapper div with `position:relative` and then constrain the size of your thumbnails to it.

(For the snippet included below, I changed your col-* classes to XS so they would show correctly at all sizes.)

```css
.positioningDiv {
    position:relative;
}

.front{
 transform:perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
 backface-visibility:hidden;
 transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}
.back{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
 transform:perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
 backface-visibility:hidden;
 transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
 border:1px solid #000;
}
.flip3d:hover .front{
 transform:perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
}
.flip3d:hover .back{
 transform:perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
}
.caption span{
 font-size:large;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="items_row1" >
        <div class="item col-xs-4 flip3d">
            <div class="positioningDiv">
                <div class="thumbnail front" id="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"/>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <span>Front1 &nbsp;</span>
                        <p>Front1 Description</p>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.thumbnail-->
                <div class="back thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"/>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <span>Back1 &nbsp;</span>
                        <p>Back1 Description</p>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item col-xs-4 flip3d">
            <div class="positioningDiv">
                <div class="thumbnail front" id="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"/>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <span>Front2 &nbsp;</span>
                        <p>Front2 Description</p>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.thumbnail-->
                <div class="back thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"/>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <span>Back2 &nbsp;</span>
                        <p>Back2 Description</p>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- / .items_row1 -->
</div>
```